# npm install is getting stuck on sill doParallel extraxt xxxx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, angular, amazon-ec2, npm

sudo npm insatll is working fine on local but after I pulled code in EC2 ubuntu macine npm install is getting stuck on some

"sill doParallel extraxt 1103"

I am unable to resolve it from quite some time

my package.json is looking like this...

[image]

Comment: Tear apart your package.json and remove the larger modules from it. Then `npm install` to see whether it still get stuck. It must be one or more of the modules that's causing it if you can find out which then it'll help you debug it by a whole lot.

Comment: Hey Arun, did you end up finding out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this error.

**sill doParallel extract 1**

on this line installing packages stopped.

I had node 6.11.0 uninstall and install 6.11.5.

started working (y)